# Como carregar somente se clicado

Tags: javascript, ajax, carregamento

Estou criando uma página de vídeos, onde nela é listada os últimos 10. Só que essa página esta muito pesada, pois tenho os códigos dos vídeos e mesmo usando o recurso de esconder/mostrar ele acaba por carregar todos os players.

Gostaria de uma ideia para que nesse botão mostrar o vídeo , esse código do vídeo só carregasse se clicado. Pensei em `ajax`, mas estou quebrando a cabeça aqui .. 
Só complementando faço a `query` e volta as `urls-video`

exemplo

```
foreach ($query as $res)
{
    <div class="pre-spoiler">
        <input name="xs" type="button"  class="xs" onClick="
            if(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display != 'none')
            {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'none'; 
                this.value = 'Zuklappen'; 
            } else {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'block'; 
                this.value = 'Aufklappen';
            }" value="Buttontext">

        <div class="spoiler" style="display: none;">
*****<?php echo $res['url-video']?>***=>aqui é o ponto, que so queria que ele carregasse se clicado no botao...
    </div>
}
```

Comment: ex ..ja volta o codigo embed 
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/y6Sxv-sUYtM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: so que ele carrega todos os playes